# What is the difference between ifne and ifnonnull?

Tags: java, bytecode

I've just read through [Java bytecode instruction listings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings) and wondered:

**What is the difference between `ifne` and `ifnonnull` in Java Bytecode?**

I know that in a high level language (e.g. Java) the value `0` is an numeric value that has some operations (like addition, subtraction, multiplication) and can be compared to other numeric values whereas `null` is a value that represents "no value".

I guess one problem I have is that I don't know how `null` might be represented in Bytecode / assembly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JVM specification is perhaps clearer on this.

So for [`ifne` (and `ifeq` etc)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.10.1.9.if_cond) the restriction is:

> An `ifeq` instruction is type safe iff one can validly pop a type matching int off the incoming operand stack yielding the outgoing type state NextStackFrame, and the operand of the instruction, Target, is a valid branch target assuming an incoming type state of NextStackFrame.

Whereas for [`ifnonnull`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.10.1.9.ifnonnull) the restriction is:

> An ifnonnull instruction is type safe iff one can validly pop a type matching reference off the incoming operand stack yielding the outgoing type state NextStackFrame, and the operand of the instruction, Target, is a valid branch target assuming an incoming type state of NextStackFrame.

Basically `ifeq` and `ifne` are for integer values, whereas `ifnonnull` is for a reference value.

To compare two references for equality, you use [`if_acmpeq`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.10.1.9.if_acmp_cond) instead. `ifnonnull` is effectively a special case of that where there's only *one* operand, because it's always just compared with null.

In terms of how the `null` reference is represented in *data*, the JVM specification [explicitly allows this to be implementation-specific](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.4):

> A reference value may also be the special null reference, a reference to no object, which will be denoted here by null. The null reference initially has no run-time type, but may be cast to any type. The default value of a reference type is null.
>
> The Java Virtual Machine specification does not mandate a concrete value encoding null.

Comment: Could you please also tell me how `null` could be encoded?

Comment: @moose: Well I suspect in many cases it would be a reference value with a bit-pattern of all-zeroes, but as I say it's JVM-specific.